# Javascript Regex: Match additionals based on path delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

I'm trying to match folders/files in a repeated manner - based on the path delimiter `/`.

**Regex:**

```
/^(?:music|pictures)\/tom(?:(?=\/)\/([\w\-]+(?:\s+[\w\-]+)*)|$)$/gm
```

**Explanation of the regex above:**

```
// Match a base-directory called music/pictures
// Match if directory tom exist
// If delimiter was found, match delimiter and word-character and hypen (no spaces etc at the beginning)
// Match spaces, word-characters and hypen (no spaces etc at the end)
//If delimiter was not found, end string
//End string
```

Everytime the delimiter `/` is found (positive lookahead), it should also match the remaining conditions. It works very well except for when a subfolder hits the regex.

---

```
music/tom/foldername

music/tom/folder name

music/tom/foldername/folder2  <--- Does not match
```

As you can see the last path cannot be matched. How can I extend/improve the regex in order to match subfolders as well?

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/oG9bC3/1

Comment: so you want to match everything after `tom`?

Comment: Good morning @rock321987, yes that is correct. I want to match everything after tom (except spaces at the beginning/end) and only if a delmiter was found.

Comment: see if **[this](https://regex101.com/r/oG9bC3/3)** works..I have replace `\s` with space as `\s` matches new line

Comment: Solid work @rock321987! Thank you very much for your help. Please post this as an official answer if you want, so I can give you kudos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to get what you want

```
^(?:music|pictures)\/tom((?:\/(?:[\w-]+(?:[ ]+[\w-]+)*))+)$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oG9bC3/3)**

**NOTE**

- You don't need lookahead when you already know what you require as next character.
- `-` is not required to be escaped when it is used in *first/last* of **`character class`.